# Hiding textbox of the file Uploading browse button

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring, file-upload

The title might make the question looks older, but there is some more to it.

In order to hide the textbox of the browse button, i added the following code.

```
 <html:form action="/validate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <html:file property="file" id="selectedFile" style="display: none;" />
    <input type="button" value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();" />
   <html:sumbit/>
 </html:form>
```

It works well till selecting the files. I'm using spring for my project.

When I use this method I'm not able to get the file to the class method. I need the textbox to be hidden. Following is the code I used in the class.

```
 public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        FileUploadForm uploadForm = (FileUploadForm) form;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        FormFile formFile = null;
        try {
            formFile = uploadForm.getFile();
            String path = getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("") + "/" + formFile.getFileName();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
            outputStream.write(formFile.getFileData());
        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
        uploadForm.setMessage("The file " + formFile.getFileName() + " is uploaded successfully.");
        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }
```

Since the file is not receriving here, it shows FileNotFound exception. **The code runs fine If i use normal browse button with textbox**. But the requirement is like, the textbox should be hidden. And the button shouldn't messed up with css too. Any thoughts what's going wrong.

Comment: dont use js, it won't work well. turn off the onclick and wrap a <label> tag around both the hidden file input and the do-nothing button.

Comment: instead of `display:none` use `visibility:hidden`, so that you can access the file name.

Comment: @dandavis I'm not getting you. the default browse button and text filed is not displayed. You saying wrap this button in `label` and let the label do opening the file explorer ?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai If I use `visibility:hidden`, even though it is hidden, won't it still occupy that much space ?

Comment: hide the file upload, using opacity and size. then put a label with a _for_ attrib set to the id of the file upload. put a button without any events in the label. you can now click the dummy button and it will open the file dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `display:none`, use `height:0;width:0;opacity:0;`

### Why?

When you use `display:none` the element is removed completely from the document structure hence is not *sensed* in your code.

> Please note that a display of 'none' does not create an invisible box;
>   it creates no box at all.
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display

Comment: @smashIT, Is the element visible after the _style_ modification or is it invisible and still not getting detected after the change?